# In TypeScript, how to define a recursive function that return a promise

Tags: typescript, promise, settimeout

We still use angular 1.5.8 and I try to write a function that breaks a long computation to parts. Since a promise can be chained with function that return promises, I thought of writing it like that:

```
interface IResult {
    add(s: string): void { ... }
}

function buildResult(): IResult { ... }
function handleItem(s: string): string { ... }

function doWork(data: string[]): ng.IPromise<IResult> {
    let i = 0;
    const result = buildResult();

    const process = (): ng.IPromise<IResult> => {
        for(let start = i; i < start + 100; ++i) {
            const item = data[i];
            if(!item) {
                return $q.resolve(result);
            }
            result.add(handleItem(item));
        }

        return $timeout(process, 20)
    }

    return process();
}
```

This works, but TypeScript compiler complains because Angular $timeout service accepts a function that return a value, not a promise:

> TS2322:Type 'IPromise<IPromise>' is not assignable to type 'IPromise'. Property 'add' is missing in type 'IPromise<IResult>'.

Is there a way to properly define the types in this function?

I can see two options to go:

1. Define process to return `any`
2. Cast the return statement:

`return $timeout(process, 20) as any as ng.IPromise<IResult>`

Any better idea?

Answer (score 0):

$timeout signature is:

```
interface ITimeoutService {
    (delay?: number, invokeApply?: boolean): IPromise<void>;
    <T>(fn: (...args: any[]) => T, delay?: number, invokeApply?: boolean, ...args: any[]): IPromise<T>;
    cancel(promise?: IPromise<any>): boolean;
}
```

(See https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/angular/index.d.ts#L603)

Thus, `$timeout(process, 20)` returns a `IPromise<IPromise<IResult>>`, that throws a TS2322 error. But how your code works? Looking at $timeout implementation we see the answer:

```
...
deferred.resolve(fn.apply(null, args));
...
```

`$timeout` creates a new deferred and resolves it like `deferred.resolve(fn.apply(null, args));`, working as a promise chain when fn returns a promise.

So, the problem here is the $timeout signature! $timeout signature should be:

```
interface ITimeoutService {
    (delay?: number, invokeApply?: boolean): IPromise<void>;
    <T>(fn: (...args: any[]) => T | IPromise<T>, delay?: number, invokeApply?: boolean, ...args: any[]): IPromise<T>;
    cancel(promise?: IPromise<any>): boolean;
}
```

An illustrative test case can be seen [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20ITimeoutService%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(delay%3F%3A%20number%2C%20invokeApply%3F%3A%20boolean)%3A%20Promise%3Cvoid%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CT%3E(fn%3A%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20T%20%7C%20Promise%3CT%3E%2C%20delay%3F%3A%20number%2C%20invokeApply%3F%3A%20boolean%2C%20...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%3A%20Promise%3CT%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20cancel(promise%3F%3A%20Promise%3Cany%3E)%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20var%20%24timeout%3A%20ITimeoutService%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IResult%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20add(s%3A%20string)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20buildResult()%3A%20IResult%20%7B%20return%20null%20%7D%3B%0D%0Afunction%20handleItem(s%3A%20string)%3A%20string%20%7B%20return%20null%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20doWork(data%3A%20string%5B%5D)%3A%20Promise%3CIResult%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20i%20%3D%200%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20result%20%3D%20buildResult()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20process%20%3D%20()%3A%20Promise%3CIResult%3E%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for(let%20start%20%3D%20i%3B%20i%20%3C%20start%20%2B%20100%3B%20%2B%2Bi)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20item%20%3D%20data%5Bi%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if(!item)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Promise.resolve(result)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20result.add(handleItem(item))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%24timeout(process%2C%2020)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20process()%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20).

Comment: It was solved here https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/15364.